# PHP jQuery countdown for multiple values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

So I am trying to have a countdown for each value from a database. The value is in seconds and i am wanting to countdown from (let's say **100**) to **0** and then display **Finished**

However, when I tried this my results got all muddled up and were not counting down in intervals of 1 second. If there were **3** results then it counted down in intervals of **3**.
I apologise in advance for my lack of knowledge regarding this.

This is my code for it all

```
<?php

    $curtime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    $curtime = strtotime("$curtime UTC");
    if (logged_in() === true){

        $results = $dbc->query($sql);

        while ($attacks = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
            $attime = $attacks['date'] - ($attacks['length'] + $curtime);

?>

<tr>
    <td class="text-left"><?php echo $attacks['attack_ip'];?></td>
    <td class="text-left"><?php echo $attacks['port'];?></td>
    <td class="text-left"><?php echo $attacks['method'];?></td>

    //////This is where the countdown is//////
    <td id="<?php echo $attacks['attack_id'];?>" class="text-left"><?php echo $attime;?></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-square btn-danger">Stop</button></td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var sec = <?php echo $attime;?>;
    var timer = setInterval(function() { 
       $('td#<?php echo $attacks['attack_id'];?>').text(sec--);
       if (sec == -1) {
          $('td#<?php echo $attacks['attack_id'];?>');
          clearInterval(timer);
       }
       if (sec == -1) {
          $('td#<?php echo $attacks['attack_id'];?>').html("<b>Finished</b>");
          clearInterval(timer);
       }
    }, 1000);

</script>


<?php 
        } //End WHILE

    }//END IF
?>
```

Comment: PHP runs, then JS runs. You should output the page then send ajax requests to get the data you need in the intervals you want. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8uaXY.gif

Comment: @chris85 no need for ajax to do this

Comment: @charlietfl how else can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would suggest is not coupling php code with javascript. It makes it much harder to read and harder to maintain.

This can all be done by using a common class on the common elements. As for the interval times we can add those directly to the elements using `data-` attributes

HTML

```
<td class="text-left my-timer" data-time="<?php echo $attime;?>"><?php echo $attime;?></td>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    // loop over each element to activate
    $('td.my-timer').each(function(){
          // "this" inside "each" is current element
          var $elem = $(this), 
               // get the time value stored in data-time attribute
               sec = +$elem.data('time');
          // instance specific interval
          var timer = setInterval(function() {
             sec--;
             var html = sec >= 0 ? sec : "<b>Finished</b>";
             $elem.html(html);
             if( sec === 0){
                clearInterval(timer);
             }

          },1000);
    });

});
```

JS is now separated from server code and can be placed in same file or external js file

Comment: How could I make it add the class "disabled" to the button bellow it once it is Finished?

Comment: `$(this).next().find('button').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Thanks again buddy, I really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: sorry to bug you but the "Finished thing doesnt work" :/ 
Any idea why? It just stays at 0.

Comment: ok...use the -1 to kill timer instead of 0 ...that's if you want to see 0. Otherwise change `>=0` to `>0` and leave timer alone

Comment: and would I add the `$(this).next().find('button').prop('disabled', true);` line directly below like

`var html = sec > 0 ? sec : "<b>Finished</b>";
$(this).next().find('button').prop('disabled', true); `

Comment: not sure when it is disabled....after time runs out or before? If after put in condition that clears interval. Otherwise would disable in html (php) and do the opposite `prop('disabled', false)`

Comment: It's after so I have done 
`if( sec == 0){
                      clearInterval(timer);
                      $(this).next().find('button').prop('disabled', true);
                   }` 
This is not working sadly :( I also tried setting it to false.

Comment: oops ..change to `$elem.next()....` I forgot was inside an interval function closure and `this` isn't the `<td>` in there